# I am unable to get xpath to fetch all colors for walmart page by using Google docs

Tags: xpath

I am unable to get xpath to fetch colors for walmart page. Here is my xpath (//div[@class='js-product-variant-row product-variant-row']/@data-id)[2].

http://www.walmart.com/ip/44786488 - for this walmart page.
Here Iam getting many swaches in color,I want to know how to take all colors in different urls
(for example)I have walmart page, in that there are two types of color for that product page(Black and White). For Black I need separate url and for White I need separate url. I need both color as different url.
Kindly help me

Comment: can you clarify your question. Its still not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Even though, your question is not much clear, I somehow tried to understand your point and thought, below might resolve your problem. If not, pls specify your exact problem, that you wanted to fetch.

If you need all the colors, below gives the title attributes specifying the color name.

```
//*[contains(@for,'actual_color')]/span/@title
```

If you need only names of all the colors, try below.

```
string(//*[contains(@for,'actual_color')]/span/@title)
```